# apache not starting and does not have proper message on logs

Tags: apache, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I have tried to configure apache using puppet. When I try to start apache it is failing with out any proper error message. I am not figure out why it is failing. I tried executing the below commands it just say failed to start and does not show any specific reason why it failed to start. Could you please let me know how to figure out what is happening? I am attaching my log file below.

```
systemctl status httpd.service
journalctl -xe


Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname httpd[18999]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname httpd[18999]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname kill[19001]: kill: cannot find process ""
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname audispd[414]: node=hostname type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1471316163.292:57410): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname polkitd[532]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:18984:32063862 (system bus name :1.15792, object path /org/freedesktop/P
```

Comment: can you try telnet to 80 or port you configured on httpd to see if any other application is already using ports that apache is using ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your best hint is

```
Aug 15 22:56:03 hostname httpd[18999]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Looks like another process is listening on the socket that tomcat is trying to listen on, which is 8080 by default or you can check conf to see what is set

You can use command like

```
 lsof -i TCP |grep 8080
```

To get process id of what is listening on that port and track it down in `top` or whatever

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem, the default configuration of puppet has commented out the listen port in httpd.conf and added a port.conf. But as i have not explicitly configured the listen port, apache did not had a default port to listen. I have configured the port and it started working.